# RegEx: Match "year:2012" anywhere in a string?

Tags: regex, search, digit

I'm working on a search engine, and i need the user to be able to filter the results by year. I want the user to be able to add "year:(four digits)" anywhere in the search string. I created this but it's not quite what i want:

```
(year\:\d{4})
```

It does indeed match what i need, but i only want to match if there is either whitespace or nothing next to it. Right now, it matches even if it's in the middle of a word.

Examples:

```
testyear:2012test - Don't want match
test year:2012test - Don't want match
test year:2012 test - DO want match
test year:2012 - DO want match
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use word boundaries '\b' around the regex to guarantee that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundaries:

```
\b(year:\d{4})\b
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below regex:

```
\byear:\d{4}\b
```

`\b` matches the word boundary